# some webpages are not opening "The site can't be reached" on newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after resetting the router

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns

It worked perfectly as soon Ubuntu installed, but when I reset the router to default configuration some webpages not loading only on Ubuntu.

I followed by changing `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file appending

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

nothing worked for me. Only some pages are opening others got **"The site can't be reached"** **ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE** Error.

Please help me to fix this. The wifi icon remains with the question mark on top.

check this if it helps : https://justpaste.it/8kre7

Answer (score 0):

First the nameserver is for DNS your error has nothing to do with DNS its says address cant be reached. You did not say why it was necessary to reset the router to a default configuration.

Comment: I reset my router just for changing the password to default and had some connectivity strength issue

Comment: I have mistakenly deleted contents on /etc/resolv,conf file. can someone provide me what is the default entries to Ubuntu 20.04. One is nameserver #### and there was another entry starting with 'option' I guess but I can not recall what was the value for that